# Angular $routeParams is blank

Tags: angularjs

I have a really simple Angular app that I've distilled to the following:

```
var napp = angular.module('Napp',['ngResource']);

var CompanyCtrl = function($scope, $routeParams, $location, $resource) {
    console.log($routeParams);
};


napp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
    .when('/company/edit/:id', 
      {templateUrl: '/partials/edit', controller: 'CompanyCtrl'}
    );
}]);
```

and the HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="CompanyCtrl"></div>
```

When I log $routeParams, it comes up blank. When I use .otherwise(), it will load whatever I've specified there. Any idea what I'm missing?

Comment: can u see what you are getting in $route.current.params.id

Comment: See if this addresses your issue: http://deansofer.com/posts/view/14/AngularJs-Tips-and-Tricks-UPDATED#routing

Comment: $route is just like $routeprovider so inject $route in the controller definition and try to print above value

Comment: This is what I see:  http://wes.io/PaDD — Injecting it like this: http://wes.io/PZi7

Comment: $routeParams isn't going to be available to your controller's constructor when it's called.  Inject it when you need it -- don't assume you have context-sensitive information when a controller is being instantiated -- use the context-sensitive stuff when it's being linked.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all try this with

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

That should fix your starting code. Then adjust your code to support non-pushState browsers.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How and where to use it?

Answer (score 10):

You have a couple of errors:

2. You've specified the controller in two places, both in the view (`<div ng-controller="CompanyCtrl"></div>`) and in $routeProvider (`.when('/company/edit/:id', {templateUrl: '/partials/edit', controller: 'CompanyCtrl'}`). I'd remove the one in the view.
3. You have to register the controller in the module when specifying it in the $routeProvider (you should really do this anyway, it's better to avoid global controllers). Do `napp.controller('CompanyCtrl', function ...` instead of `var CompanyCtrl = function ...`.
4. You need to specify a [ng-view](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngView) when you're using the $route service (not sure if you're doing this or not)

The new code:

```js
var napp = angular.module('Napp', ['ngResource']);

napp.controller('CompanyCtrl', function ($scope, $routeParams, $location, $resource) {
  console.log($routeParams);
});

napp.config(['$routeProvider', function ($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider
    .when('/company/edit/:id',
      {templateUrl: '/partials/edit', controller: 'CompanyCtrl'}
    );
}]);
```

The template (/parials/edit)

```
<div> ... </div>
```

And the app (index.html or something)

```
... <body> <div ng-view></div> </body>
```

I've created a working plunker example: http://plnkr.co/edit/PQXke2d1IEJfh2BKNE23?p=preview

Comment: using ng-view when using the $route service was a big thing i needed to understand but wasn't apparent to me. Also i never realized that when using routing you only should declare the controller in the $routeProvider and not also in the view. makes sense. thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this helps, but I just came across this issue myself, and found that I couldn't log the route params until I had something bound to them.
So,

Router:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);
myApp.config(function($routeProvider){

  $routeProvider.when('/projects/:id', 
    {templateUrl: '/views/projects/show.html', controller: 'ProjectCtrl'}
  );

});
```

Controller:

```
myApp.controller('ProjectCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams){
  $scope.id = $routeParams.id;
  console.log('test');
});
```

View:

```
<h1>{{ id }}</h1>
```

When I removed the '{{id}}' from the view, nothing was logged and $routeParams was empty, at least at the time of the controller's instantiation.  As some of the answers above have pointed to, the route params are passed in asynchronously, so a controller with no bindings to that property won't execute.  So, not sure exactly what you've distilled your snippet down from, but hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

This may happen (not in the OP's case) if you're using `ui-router` instead of `ngRoute`.

If that's the case, use `$stateParams` instead of `$routeParams`.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/26946824/995229

Answer (score 2):

Of course it will be blank. RouteParams is loaded asynchronously so you need to wait for it to get the params. Put this in your controller:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function() {
   console.log($routeParams); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It works for me http://plunker.co/edit/ziLG1cZg8D8cYoiDcWRg?p=preview

But you have some errors in your code:

- Your don't seem to have a [ngView](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angView) in your code. The `$routeProvider` uses the `ngView` to know where it should insert the template's content. So you need it somewhere in your page.
- You're specifying your `CompanyCtrl` in two places. You should specify it either in the `$routeProvider`, or in you template using `ng-controller`. I like specifying it in the template, but that's just personal preference.
- Although not an error, you're specifying your `CompanyCtrl` in the global scope, instead of registering it on your `Napp` module using `Napp.controller(name, fn)`.

Hope this helps!
You can always go on #angularjs irc channel on freenode: there's always active people ready to help

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that your `templateUrl` points to an invalid template?

When you change the `templateUrl` to an unexisting file, you will notice that the `$routeParams` will no longer be populated (because AngularJS detects an error when resolving the template).

I have created a working plnkr with your code for your convenience that you can just copy and paste to get your application working:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Yabp4c9zmDGQsUOa2epZ?p=preview

As soon as you click the link in the example, you will see the router in action.

Hope that helps!