# AngularJS $routeParams vs $stateParams

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-routing

What is the difference between:

```
$routeParams and $stateParams
```

and when to use what?

Answer (score 17):

Both are from different router modules. You can use anyone in your application.

If you use `ngRoute` module, then you should use `$routeParams` 
( https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute ) . This is provided by Angular team. It has only one `ng-view`. you can not do nested views functionality.

If you use `ui-router` module, then you should use `$stateParams`
( https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router ). This is from contributed module. It has number of additional functionality compare than `ngRoute` . It supports nested view concepts. you can specify multiple `ui-view`

See more: http://www.amasik.com/angularjs-ngroute-vs-ui-router/