# $routeParams Not Passing In Anything (Angular/Node)

Tags: angularjs, node.js, routes

I'm sure this problem has a simple answer, but, for once, I'm stumped. I want to have a URL like http://www.website.com/item/1234 display information about an item with id '1234'. I have an Angular controller set up to query for it and render its data. This works, provided the id is valid. However, I can't figure out how to pass the id, in the first place. I have tried lots of routing examples, but none of them work when I try to implement them, so I'm missing something.

Here is the server route in Express/Node:

```
    router.get('/item/:id', function(req, res, next) {
        res.render('item');
    });
```

Here is the Angular route:

```
    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider.when('/item/:id', {
            controller: 'ShowItem'
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
```

The controller is trying to access 'id' here:

```
    app.controller('ShowItem', ['$scope', '$http', '$routeParams', function($scope, $http, $routeParams) {
        console.log($routeParams.id);
        var itemID = $routeParams.id;
        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/queries/get_item',
            params: {
                itemID: itemID
            }
        }).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            if (data) {
                $scope.itemValue = data;
                $scope.type = $scope.itemValue['SaleType'];
                $scope.setAllBidHistory(false);
                if (Date.getStamp() >= $scope.itemValue['ExpirationTimeStamp']) {
                    $scope.expired = true;
                } else {
                    $scope.expired = false;
                }
            }
        }).error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            alert('There was an error fetching item: '+status);
        });
                                   ...
    }]);
```

The page renders, but $routeParams.id is undefined.

Comment: You can try that http://stackoverflow.com/a/17177449/1731636

Comment: Do you have a plunker for this maybe?